# PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening '/controllers/usuarioController.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /app/autoload.php on line

Tags: php, heroku

estuve haciendo un curso y por fin al terminarlo quise llevarlo a producción y subirlo a un host, opte por heroku y levante la db correctamente, cuando quiero utilizar alguna de las funciones de la pagina al utilizar modelos no me los carga (utilizo un autoloader para cargar las clases pero al parecer no esta funcionando.

[image: console log]

PHP Warning:  include(/controllers/ErrorController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/autoload.php on line 4

Bueno basicamente lo que dice la consola de heroku es que no puede encontrar el archivo autoload. :/

Y aqui un pantallazo de la disposicion de archivos
[image: disposicion de archivos]

Por ultimo el codigo del autoloader

```
<?php

function controllers_autoload($classname){
    include 'controllers/'.$classname.'.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('controllers_autoload');
```

y el del index para llamar al autoload

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'helpers/utils.php';
require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once 'config/Parameters.php';
require_once 'config/Database.php';
require_once 'views/layout/header.php';
require_once 'views/layout/sidebar.php';

if (isset($_GET['controller'])) {
    $nControlador = $_GET['controller'];
    $nControlador .= 'Controller';
} elseif (!isset($_GET['controller']) && !isset($_GET['action'])) {
    $nControlador = controller_default;
} else {
    show_error();
    echo '<p>Se espera un controlador por la url (?controller="controlador")</p>';
}

if (!class_exists($nControlador)) {
    show_error();
    echo '<p>El controlador indicado no existe o no se encuentra disponible</p> <br>';

    var_dump($nControlador);

    if(class_exists('Categoria')){
        echo 'existe la clase Categoria | ';
    } else {
        echo 'no se registro el modelo Categoria | ';
    }
     

    if(class_exists('cartController')){
        echo 'existe la clase cartController | ';
    } else {
        echo 'no se registro la clase cartController | ';
    }

    if(class_exists('errorController')){
        echo 'existe la clase errorController';
    } else {
        echo 'no se registro la clase errorController';
    }

} else {
    $controlador = new $nControlador();

    if (isset($_GET['action']) && method_exists($controlador, $_GET['action'])) {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        $controlador->$action();
    } elseif (!isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $action = action_default;
        $controlador->$action();
    } else {
        show_error();
        echo '<p>El metodo buscado no fue encontrado o aun no ha sido diseñado</p>';
        
    }
}


function show_error()
{
    $error = new ErrorController();
    $error->index();
}


require_once 'views/layout/footer.php';
```

Si alguien pudiera darme una mano estaria totalmente agradecido, llevo un monton de tiempo tratando de resolver los problemas que aparecen al levantar el proyecto en un host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar rutas absolutas y, ya que todo pasa por *index.php*, ahí puedes definir una constante, usando la [constante predefinida de PHP `__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php), que te devuelve la ruta en disco del archivo actual.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Definir constante con directorio actual
define('PROY_RUTA', __DIR__);

require_once 'helpers/utils.php';
require_once 'autoload.php';
require_once 'config/Parameters.php';
require_once 'config/Database.php';
require_once 'views/layout/header.php';
require_once 'views/layout/sidebar.php';
```

Cada que necesites incluir o guardar otro archivo usas esa constante:

```
<?php

function controllers_autoload($classname){
    // Usa la constante para tener la ruta completa
    $script = PROY_RUTA . "/controllers/"$classname.php";
    // Verifica que el archivo existe antes de incluirlo
    if(file_exists($script)) {
        include $script;
    } else {
        die("No existe el archivo de controlador para <b>$classname</b>.");
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('controllers_autoload');
```

Supongamos que quieres guardar un archivo de texto en *assets/documents*:

```
$contenido = 'Esto se va a guardar en un archivo de texto';
file_put_contents(PROY_RUTA . '/assets/documents/archivo.txt', $contenido);
```

Comment: Si seguramente se me olvido de añadir eso, tengo una variable global llamada base_url para llamarla cada vez traigo los objetos de la base de datos, probe con añadirlo al autoloader y funcionó, por alguna razon en local no era necesario. Gracias