# Problemas para utilizar el Include en php

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un proyecto en PHP, sin utilizar frameworks o librerias.
Tengo porblemas con el manejo de las rutas.

Yo en todos mis archivos PHP, necesito llamar a un `header.php` y a un `footer.php` con `include`.
Dentro del Header tengo otro include

```
include_once('../assets/includes/functions.php');
```

el Header se encuentra en la siguente ruta

```
/views/header.php
```

Dentro de `/views/admision/indicadores/` tengo un archivo .php que necesito incluir al header.php, pero cuando lo incluyo, me dice que desde el header no puede encontrar `../assets/includes/functions.php`

Trate de usar el siguente codigo, pero la ruta del servidor donde se publica la app es diferente, este codigo no me funciona.

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/views/header.php");
```

Y si utilizo `__DIR__` la ruta aparece rara

```
(C:\p\projectos\tableros\tableros\Utils/views/header.php)
```

Antes de `Utils` aparece `\` y despues de `Utils` aparece `/`

Cual es la mejor practica para solucionar este problema de rutas relativas?

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/385132/54039) tal vez pueda serte útil.

Comment: No me funcione, ahi esta recomendando usar __DIR__ pero en mi caso no se porque no funciona, me sucede lo que explique a lo ultimo.

Comment: ¿Cómo manejas las rutas? a) Todo pasa por index.php b) Cada página entra directo al script PHP c) Otra opción (explica, por favor). ¿Tienes un archivo que siempre debas incluir, como configuración o conexión a base de datos?

Comment: No manejo un sistemas de rutas, voy llamar con href a los .php
Si, tengo 3 archivos que siempre deben estar, que son justamente para conectarse y hacer consultar a una BD,

Comment: En uno de esos archivos es donde defines una constante que contenga la ruta a la carpeta principal de tu proyecto y, después, usas esa misma constante para incluir otros archivos.

Comment: Como defino la ruta principal del proyecto? No la del servidor, porque en mi entorno local no tengo problema, pero en produccion si tengo problema

Comment: Revisa la respuesta que mencioné al principio, ahí dice cómo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo más simple y mantenible es que definas todas tus rutas en un archivo de rutas. Luego, donde vayas a usar rutas incluyes ese archivo y usas las constantes predefinidas. Una de las grandes ventajas de esto es que la ruta estará definida en un solo sitio y si necesitas cambiar algo lo cambias sólo ahí. En el resto del código, aunque uses miles de rutas, usarás siempre las constantes. Imagina tener que buscar entre miles de archivos para cambiar una ruta.

Para más praticidad, puedes definir las rutas en cascada, o sea, usar la constante del padre en el hijo.

Veamos un ejemplo:

Aquí asumimos que `views` y `assets` están en el root. Si no es así, lo cambias.

Esto iría en un archivo llamado `dirs.php`  en tu root:

```
<?php 
    define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
    define('ASSETS', ROOT_PATH.'/assets');
    define('VIEWS', ROOT_PATH.'/views');
    define('INCLUDES', ASSETS.'/includes');
    define('ADMISION', VIEWS.'/admision');
    define('INDICADORES', ADMISION.'/indicadores');
    #...
    #Todas tus otras rutas
?>
```

Luego, cuando necesites incluir algún archivo del proyecto, aunque sean en cientos de archivos:

```
#Incluir dirs.php donde quiera que vayas a trabajas con rutas
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dirs.php');

#Usar cada constante específica
include (VIEWS."/header.php");
include (INCLUDES."/functions.php");
include (INDICADORES."/archivo.php");
```

Si `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` no te obtiene tu directorio de ruta, simplemente lo cambias por una superglobal que te lo obtenga adecuadamente.

Puedes probar un `echo INDICADORES;` por ejemplo (o cualquier otra de las constantes) para verificar que la ruta es la correcta.

Comment: No me sirve, porque como mencione:
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] no me funciona correctamente en produccion, ya que la carpeta del servidor no se encuentra en la raiz de mi proyecto

Comment: @GonzaloPiñeiro si la carpeta root de tu sitio se encuentra en otra parte y no se puede obtener por medio de la superglobal o de las constantes de PHP por ese mismo motivo, simplemente la defines manulamente en la constante `ROOT_PATH`  del archivo `dirs.php` y todo lo demás irá sobre ruedas. No hay mayor complicación.

Comment: O sea, algo así:  `define('ROOT_PATH', 'la/ruta/correcta/del/root/de/tu/sitio');`  y, en para hacer include de `dirs.php` lo mismo: `include_once ('la/ruta/correcta/del/root/de/tu/sitio/dirs.php');` Otra forma de hacerlo sería definiendo variables de entorno.

Comment: Claro ya entendi, lo voy a probar